# How to create docker volume using docker-compose file so the app can write files to when running?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-image

I have an app written using ASP.NET Core 3.1 framework. I am trying to create a docker image to allow me to run the app on a Linux system.

My app allows the user to upload files to the server, so it writes the uploaded file onto a folder called "Storage" located on the root folder of my project.

I want to create a permanent storage on the Linux machine so it is not destroyed when the image is removed.

I create the following `docker-compose.yml` file with instructions on how to create volumes as follow

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myproject:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myproject
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyProject/Dockerfile
    environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://localhost;http://localhost
    - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44344
    ports:
    - 51736:80
    - 44344:443
    volumes:
      - photos:/app/Storage

volumes:
  photos:
```

According to my understanding, the `volumes` located under the `myproject` service mapps the volume that is called `photos` to `/app/Storage`.

However, I am not what command would I use to create the volume on the server so it is not deleted.

How can I correctly create a volume and point the image to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need anything else. You have everything in there already. docker-compose will automatically create the `photos` volume for you and retain it across container restarts. Check `docker volume ls` after you start this stack for the first time and you'll see the volume listed.

Comment: When I run my image using `docker image -p 44344:443 imagename:latest` I get the following error `Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /app/Storage/` so the app is unable to start because the directory is not available. When I SSH into my machine and execute cd /app/Storage` I get no such a file or directory

Comment: You need to run `docker-compose up` to use the `docker-compose.yml` you wrote.

Comment: `docker-compose build` is used to create the image. Then `docker push` to push it to the hub. Then on the VM, I execute `docker run ...` to download and run the app on the VM. When I execute `docker-compose` command not found. Doesn't docker-compose build create the image with everything found in the dockerfile and the `docker-compose.yml` file?